# I am getting error outOfMemoryError Java Heap Space while executing project

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I am getting error **outOfMemoryError** Java Heap Space while executing project..

My project is on Theft detection of Java Programs by using a *birthmark* technique.. A heapsnapshot is taken from google chrome developer tools where it contains lots of nodes to store in the database.. Am using **netbeans** Ide **MYSQL** databse..

When inserting the heapsnapshot nodes into databse am getting the error "`java.lang.outOfMemory exception Java Heap Space`" and sometimes another error related to that like "`Exception in FilterChainExecution`". Am getting this error from last 2 months.

I tries all other options like **-Xmx512m -Xmx1024m -Xmx2048m     -Xms512m..** but couldnot solve Please help me..

Comment: which java version are you using?

Comment: Use a tool like VisualVm, JConsole... of your JDK

Answer (score 0):

The immediate cause of your problem is that your application is filling the heap.  (Obviously!  That is what an OOME means.)

The band-aid solution that you have been trying is to make the heap progressively larger, and larger with various `-Xmx...` arguments.  Apparently it isn't working.  You keep increasing the heap size and the problem recurs anyway.

This suggests that your real problem is that you either have a memory leak, or you application has to hold / assemble too much data in memory before it can save it to the database.

If the problem is a memory leak, there are numerous resources on the web on how to detect and fix memory leaks in Java programs.

If the problem is that your in-memory data structures are too large, then you need to figure out a way to reduce them.  That's probably something we can't help you with.

---

The "Exception in FilterChainExecution" could be something different, or it could merely a consequence of the OOME exceptions.  We'd need to see the full stacktrace to be able to answer that.